# tableview, change font color of focus tvos

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos

How do you change the font color of a "focused" UITableView cell? I currently have this....

```
 - (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
if (context.nextFocusedView) {
    CategoryCell *cell = [self.categoryTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryCell"];
    [cell.categoryLbl setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
     }
 }
```

I know that if you want to change a background of a focused UITableViewCell it would be:

```
   - (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
    [context.nextFocusedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[context.previouslyFocusedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
 }
```

Comment: The issue above is that you are creating new cells (dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier), not modifying the existing cells. See answer below about using cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `TVOS` `UITableViewDelegate` have new method `tableView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:` which will be called when focus change, you can get previous IndexPath and nextFocusIndexPath and then you can use tableView methods to get cells, your code should look like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath = [context previouslyFocusedIndexPath];
    if (prevIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor white];
    }
    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
    if (nextIndexPath)
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } 
}
```

Please visit this [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:) for more detail

Comment: i tried this and only the first cell changes the font color but if i scroll down and focus on another cell, the text color does not change

Comment: I have update code, and this code I am using and working for me

Comment: Thanks! I'll post my swift solution below

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach using Swift 2.0 :)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let prevIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath { 
        let prevCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(prevIndexPath)
        prevCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    if let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath {
        let nextCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(nextIndexPath)
        nextCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if `nextFocusedIndexPath` is not nil, while the previous is `nil`.

Comment: done :) answer updated so it takes all scenarios into consideration

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution in swift 2.0.

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if ((context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath) != nil) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath!)
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        if ((context.nextFocusedIndexPath) != nil) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(context.nextFocusedIndexPath!)
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should learn about the `if let foo = bar` idiom in Swift. Whenever you do something like `context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath!` (I mean the `!` here), you're most likely doing something un-swifty :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to achieve in Swift 5.2:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let prevIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath {
        let prevCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: prevIndexPath) as! TVHomeCell
        prevCell.titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .medium)
    }

    if let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath {
        let nextCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) as! TVHomeCell
        nextCell.titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: .bold)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change colour by using context , it contain reference of previously focused cell and the  current cell that is focused. just cast it to your cell type and then perform the colour change operation.

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
   
    if let prevIndex = context.previouslyFocusedItem{
        
        if let myCell = prevIndex as? Mycell {
            
            myCell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            
        }
    }
    
    if let nextIndex = context.nextFocusedItem {
        if let myCell = nextIndex as? MyCell {
            
            myCell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)